# How to print this java code to console without errors?

Tags: java, string

```
public static void stripComments(Scanner input) {
    System.out.println("import java.util.*;");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("public class Program {");
    System.out.println("    public static void main(String[] args) {");
    System.out.println("      System.out.println(\"Hello, world!\");");
    System.out.println("    }");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("    public static  void foo() {");
    System.out.println("        System.out.println(\"Goodbye!\");");
    System.out.println("    }");
    System.out.println("}");
}
```

I am trying to print this to the console without errors, but it keeps giving me an error :

```
Line 5
You may have forgotten to include a closing " mark to end a string.
unclosed string literal
    System.out.println("
                       ^
Line 5
You may have forgotten to end a statement with a semicolon. Each Java statement must end with a semicolon.
';' expected
    System.out.println("
                        ^
Line 6
This is a very general syntax error that may be caused by a variety of problems, such as misplaced { } braces or an incorrect sequence of Java keywords/operators. Sometimes the error is not on the line indicated but rather on a previous line.
illegal start of expression
    System.out.println();
          ^
Line 6
You may have forgotten to end a statement with a semicolon. Each Java statement must end with a semicolon.
';' expected
    System.out.println();
              ^
4 errors
```

It probably has to do something with escape sequences, but I can't seem where to place or put them.

Comment: This code is fine.  http://ideone.com/YeLgBn

Answer (score 3):

> System.out.println("      System.out.println(''Hello, world!'');");

I'm guessing that is line 7.

In java you use "\" as the escape character. So your code should probably be:

```
System.out.println("      System.out.println(\"Hello, world!\");");
```

Comment: Still doesn't work. I'' update the op with full code and escape sequences.

Comment: @Lompang, `I'' update the op with full code` - we can't execute that code. Put the code in a main() method and test your code that way. If it still doesn't work you have the complete code that you can post, so we can copy/compile/execute to see what you are doing wrong.

Answer (score -3):

```
public class Parallel
{   
  public static void main( String[] args )
  { 


System.out.println("import java.util.*;\n\n\npublic class Program {\n\n\tpublic static void main(String[] args) {\n\t\tSystem.out.println(''Hello, world!'');\n\t }\n\t public static  void foo() {\n\t\tSystem.out.println(''Goodbye!'');\n\t}\n}");


    }
}
```

i had the project named Parallel ready so i just did it there

when it comes down to printing lines that are inside the  "" u need to use \n for nee line and \t for tab, eclipse will not mix up ur letters with ur commands its rather easy.

Comment: He doesn't 'need to use `\n` for newline'. `println()` provides one.